# How to add queries in model in Cakephp 2.x and call that function in controller

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I want to add my save, update, find queries in model and call those functions in controller, rather than adding the queries in controller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's you precisely want to acheive, but I first of all hope you know that CakePHP has implemented save, update and find functions for your models. If not, look at the docs, e.g. here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html

If you want to add functions with custom queries to your model, you can simply add them as a normal function in your model, e.g.:

**MODEL**

```php
public function myMethod(){
    // Fetch data
    return $this->query("SELECT * FROM pictures LIMIT 2;");
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```php
public function index(){
    // Get data from model-method
    $data = $this->ModelName->myMethod();  

    // Send data to view
    $this->set(compact('data'));
}
```

---

In your **model classes you don't have to refer to your model in your code**:

- In your **controller**: `$this->ModelName->function()`
- In your **model**: `$this->function()`

Has the same meaning.